# How can I list the changes that have been made in an apt repository (server side)

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I know from an `apt update && apt list --upgradable`, that there is an upgrade available for a specific package.

Now I am interested in the exact timestamp when that upgrade has been published in the repository.

To be specific, the package in question is `openmediavault` from `http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/ erasmus/main amd64 Packages`

As I am writing this question, the version in the repo is `3.0.92` and the server-side change from `3.0.91` to the newer version most likely happened during the last 24 hours. But when exactly?

My system is Debian 8 "Jessie"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won’t get a list of changes over the whole repository, but you can view the timestamps of files on the server: add `pool` to the main URL, and explore from there. The `openmediavault` files are [here](http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/pool/main/o/openmediavault/); you’ll see the timestamps there. 3.0.92 is dated November 18 at 10:44 (in the server’s timezone).

Comment: Thank you so much, I was not aware of the pool directory!